# command line pass Q and Y to license agreement

Tags: ubuntu, bash, command-line-interface, ubuntu-18.04

I have to accept command line agreement before building the project. Key `Q` need to press to go to end of the agreement page and then need to press `Y` or `y`. I have tried

`printf 'qy\n' | source ../digi-2.4/mkproject.sh`

`printf '\ny\n' | LESS='+q' source ../digi-2.4/mkproject.sh`

Nothing worked. Whats is correct way to do this in command line ?

This is the license function

```
do_license() {
        local MKP_LICENSE_FILES=" \
                ${MKP_SCRIPTPATH}/sources/meta-digi/meta-digi-arm/DIGI_EULA \
                ${MKP_SCRIPTPATH}/sources/meta-digi/meta-digi-arm/DIGI_OPEN_EULA \
                ${MKP_SCRIPTPATH}/sources/meta-freescale/EULA \
        "
        [ -z "${MKP_PAGER+x}" ] && MKP_PAGER="| more"
        eval cat - "${MKP_LICENSE_FILES}" <<-_EOF_ ${MKP_PAGER}; printf "\n"
                +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                |                                                                               |
                |                                                                               |
                |  This software depends on libraries and packages that are covered by the      |
                |  following licenses:                                                          |
                |                                                                               |
                |      * Digi's end user license agreement                                      |
                |      * Digi's third party and open source license notice                      |
                |      * NXP Semiconductors' software license agreement                         |
                |                                                                               |
                |  To have the right to use those binaries in your images you need to read and  |
                |  accept the licenses.                                                         |
                |                                                                               |
                |                                                                               |
                +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

        _EOF_
        unset MKP_LICENSE_FILES MKP_PAGER

        ans=""
        while [ -z "${ans}" ]; do
                read -p "Do you accept all three license agreements? [y/Y to accept]: " ans
        done
        printf "%80s\n\n" | tr ' ' '-'

        [ "${ans,,}" = "y" ] || return 1
}
```

also tried setting `ans="y"`

For `echo y | source ../digi-dey-2.4/mkproject.sh` I just have to press `Q`, but till not working for `Q` and `Y`

Looking for **command line** solution to accept the license agreement.

I am on `Ubuntu-18.04`

Comment: You should look into executable if it allows unattended mode (there will probably be some swich like `--accept-tos`)

Comment: You can easily comment out the while cycle but since I dont know the license to the software you are trying to build I can't say if it is okay from legal side. and set `ans="y"`

Answer (score 0):

If it is the only problem you have you can either comment out while loop and set ans=y

```sh
#while [ -z "${ans}" ]; do
#     read -p "Do you accept all three license agreements? [y/Y to accept]: " ans
#done
ans="y"
```

or just prevent calling the function do_license()

or you can try this but without access to the whole script, it is just ques

```sh
./build.sh << EOF
q

y

EOF
```

Last think on my mind is

```sh
(echo "Q"
 echo "y") | program
```

All those ways do not consult licenses of those  softs so, please verify that you can do that.

Comment: `EOF` solution does not work `q`

Comment: @roy The script you showed don't need q to be pressed

Comment: I think its required because of `[ -z "${MKP_PAGER+x}" ] && MKP_PAGER="| more"`

Comment: @roy I edited one of the last things on my mind I can think of without having access to the file.

Comment: Nope didn't work for key `Q`

Comment: Sorry, then it will be harder to solve by emulating the input. You should take a look if you can prevent calling the function do_license()

Comment: needs details but i think this will be already solved by time